# Как начать выполнение кода только после выполнения другой функции

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такая функция:

```
$('#upload-form select[name="feedVariant"]').click();
```

Мне нужно начать выполнять код только после того как выполнится клик по указанному элементу.

Я пробовал сделать так:

```
$('#upload-form select[name="feedVariant"]').click(function () {
    alert('test');
});
```

но это не срабатывает

Comment: это срабатывает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$('#upload-form select[name="feedVariant"]').on('click', function(e) {
    alert('test');
});
```

Либо проверьте, правильно ли введены селекторы и существуют ли они.

Comment: "Попробуйте так" - с какой целью?